# Equiangular lines with symmetry requirements

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, symmetry

Listing all possible arrangements of [equiangular lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equiangular_lines) is non-trivial.

Does the problem become any easier when we additionally require that the symmetry group of that line arrangement acts transitively on the lines?